# Regular Expression : find a number near to a given String

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find a good way to capture a number that is at no more than N characters away from a given string.

For example, if the String is "age" and N=4 have to find

```
"Age 5" => 5
"My age is 10 and I my name is John" => 10
"My age is almost 5 and I my name is Mary" => null
```

In the last case, the number is separated more than 4 characters from "age".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about

```
age[^0-9]{0,4}[0-9]+
```

if you want to capture the number possibly found:

```
age[^0-9]{0,4}([0-9]+)
```

?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I prefer the \d syntax but I accept it :)

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following:

```
age[^\d]{,4}(\d+)
```

this means "age followed by 0 to 4 non-digits followed by one or more digits...capture the digits"

Comment: Thanks.  In Java you get a java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition, and "{0,4}" has to be used instead of just "{,4}"

Answer (score 0):

```
[Aa]ge[\D]{,N}(\d+)
```

and then get the contents of the first group ($1).

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the other answers here, if you need it to be within 5 characters in either direction:

```
/((\d+)\D{,4})?age(\D{,4}(\d+))?/i
```

Then:

```
if(matches[2] != null)
{
  if(matches[4] != null)
    return max(matches[2], matches[4]);  //or however you want to resolve this..
  else
    return matches[2];
}
return matches[4];
```